GeoPHP will not recognize my GeoJSON as a FeatureCollection
I am trying to get the area of each polygon.  The polygon data comes from a GeoJSON file that is a feature collection.  When I paste into geojson.io, the file works fine.  It shows a map of polygons and when I click on one, I can see the properties.  Unfortunately, I cannot get GeoPHP to recognize the same file as a FeatureCollection.  Here is my code:
public function aa_winter_sports_sq_km() {
    // Define the path to your GeoJSON file
    $geojsonFilePath = WRITEPATH . 'ski/sknowed_calcs/smaller-no-multipoly.geojson';
        
    // Check if the file exists
    if (!file_exists($geojsonFilePath)) {
        return "File does not exist!";
    }

    // Read the GeoJSON file
    $geojson = file_get_contents($geojsonFilePath);

    // Step 1: Check if it is valid JSON
    $decoded = json_decode($geojson, true);
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        return "Invalid JSON format.";
    }

    // Step 2: Check if it has a "type" property and is GeoJSON
    if (!isset($decoded['type'])) {
        return "Not a valid GeoJSON: Missing 'type' property.";
    }

    // Step 3: Load it into geoPHP
    $geometry = GeoPHP::load($geojson, 'json');

    // Step 4: Check if it is a FeatureCollection
    if ($geometry instanceof \geoPHP\Geometry\FeatureCollection) {
        return "Valid GeoJSON and it is a FeatureCollection.";
    } else {
        return "Valid GeoJSON but not a FeatureCollection.";
    }
}

If I insert the below code after step 3 for debugging purposes
// Debugging after loading
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(get_class($geometry)); // Check the class type of the loaded object
var_dump($geometry);            // Inspect the object's content
echo '</pre>';
die();

... I get the following:
string(12) "MultiPolygon"
object(MultiPolygon)#4034 (4) {
  ["geom_type":protected]=>
  string(12) "MultiPolygon"
  ["components"]=>
  array(36) {
    [0]=>
    object(Polygon)#572 (4) {
      ["geom_type":protected]=>
      string(7) "Polygon"
      ["components"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(LineString)#571 (4) {
          ["geom_type":protected]=>
          string(10) "LineString"
          ["components"]=>
          array(135) {
            [0]=>
            object(Point)#436 (5) {
              ["coords"]=>
              array(2) {
                [0]=>
                float(139.1888699)
                [1]=>
                float(36.8107625)
              }
              ["geom_type":protected]=>
              string(5) "Point"
              ["dimension":protected]=>
              int(2)
              ["geos":"Geometry":private]=>
              NULL
              ["srid":protected]=>
              NULL
            }
            [1]=>[snip]

I assume this implies is interpreting the entire GeoJSON object as a MultiPolygon instead of a FeatureCollection.  How can I get GeoPHP to recognize the file as a FeatureCollection?

It's more likely that someone will be able to help if you include a minimal geojson (as code formatted text) in your question.

And provide info about your geoPHP install as there appears to be a multitude of forks of the dead original project.

I think you are right.  It is probably not a wise allocation of time to place on GeoPHP which appears dead.  Looking other PHP packages now.  Thank you.
